# Neural Network Neurons output numbers > 1

Tags: neural-network

I have read that you calculate the output of a Neuron in a Neural Net by adding up all the inputs times their corresponding weights and then smoothing it with e.g. the Sigmoid Function.

But what I don't understand is that this sum (without smoothing) could get bigger than 1.

When this happens my Sigmoid Function outputs 1.0.

The function I am using to calculate the Neuron Output (without smoothing) is:

```
def sum(self, inputs):
    valu = 0
    for i, val in enumerate(inputs):
        valu += float(val) * self.weights[i]
    return valu
```

So my question is:
Am I doing something wrong, because I have read that the output should be between 0 and 1?

Comment: Don't really understand your question. The sum of weighted inputs can be greater than one. It can also be less than zero. The sigmoid function will map this value to a number between zero and one. Your code sample just calculates the weighted sum without applying the sigmoid function to it.

Comment: Not really if the value entered into the sigmiod function is bigger than 1 it just returns 1. Thats my problem

Comment: But how can we help you if you don't show the code of your sigmoid function? Your code sample just calculates the state of the neuron, not the output. Usually you get the output by applying ome kind of sigmoid function to the state.

Comment: Sorry about that I apply the sigmoid funktion on the returned value. I use the standard 1/(1+e^(-1*val)) where val is the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

The sigmoid function is not exactly a smoothing function, it is a non-linear function that maps the domain to the [0, 1] range in a non-linear manner. Informally speaking, a non-linear function does not have a constant slope or, in other words, it can't be described as a straight line.

The sigmoid function, as you can see in the image below, squishes the input such that, as the magnitude of the input increases, the output of the sigmoid asymptotically approximates 0 (negative input) and 1 (positive input)
[image: Sigmoid and its derivative in the [-6, 6] range]